# Weighted average of units sold at different timeframes

Tags: mean, weighted-mean

I have this weighted average:

$ S_{wavg} = 30\% * sales_{7d} + 50\% * sales_{30d} * 20\% * sales_{365d} $

Where $ sales_{xd} $ are units sold in the last X days.

1. A good approximation of this formula could be the sales of the last 90 days?

   because $ 0.3 *7 + 0.5*30 + 0.2*365 = 90 $
2. What's the timeframe of the final value $ S_{awvg} $ ? 90 days?
   Could I say that $ S_{awvg} $ are units sold in the last 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a good approximation of the sales of the last 90 days as long as cumulative sales closely follow a straight line. Here you are assuming that there is 1 sale per day (a constant rate of sales). You can think of this as a uniform distribution. This approximation will become less accurate if there are significant variations in the distribution of daily sales over the year due to seasonality or growth.
2. You can say that units sold in the last 90 days approximate $S_{awvg}$ given the conditions mentioned above. Assume that the rate of sales is constant: since days also increment at a constant rate, and the weighted average of days elapsed comes out to 90, the sales after 90 days will equal the weighted average. If the distribution of daily sales deviates significantly from the uniform, you would need to find what $S_{awvg}$ equals first, then find which day's cumulative sales are closest to it for a comparable "timeframe".